# CSR mulitple Taxonomy fields

Tags: 2013, javascript, client-side-rendering

I have multiple Taxonomy fields in my code and only one column shows up properly and the rest just don't appear.

[image: Displaying missing Field]

I'm Using CSR and JS-Link to modify my New Form in SharePoint 2013 on Premise and all my other Forms.  Every other fields are working correctly.

Here is how I generate my fields:

```
    (function () {
    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render
    var formTemplate = {};
    formTemplate.Templates = {};
    formTemplate.Templates.View = viewTemplate;
    //What actually overwrites the default table
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(formTemplate);

})();

function viewTemplate(ctx) {
    //HTML design Variable, doesn't have to be an html table
    var formTable = "".concat("<table width='100%' cellpadding='5'>",
        "<tr><td colspan='4' ><div><h1>{{LoadingDockNotification}}</h1>",
        "<p>(<!--<span class='ms-formvalidation'>--> * <!--</span>--> {{indicatesrequiredfield}})</p></div></td></tr>",
        "<tr><td style='border-bottom: thin solid #000000;' colspan='4'><h2>{{BankContactInformation}}</h2></td></tr>",
        "<tr>",
        "<td><div>{{BankContactNameLbl}} *</div></td>",
        "<td colspan='3'><div>{{BankContactNameCtrl}}</div></td>",
        "</tr>",
        "<tr>",
        '<td><div>{{BankContactNumberLbl}} *</div></td>',
        "<td colspan='3'><div>{{BankContactNumberCtrl}}</div></td>",
        '</tr>',
        "<tr>",
        "<td><div>{{BankContactDepartmentLbl}} *</div></td>",
        "<td colspan='3'><div>{{BankContactDepartmentCtrl}}</div></td>",
        '</tr>',
        '<tr>',
        "<td><div>{{AlternateBankContactNameLbl}}</div></td>",
        "<td colspan='3'><div>{{AlternateBankContactNameCtrl}}</div></td>",
        "</tr>",
        "<tr>",
        "<td><div>{{AlternateBankContactExtensionNumLbl}}</div></td>",
        "<td colspan='3'><div>{{AlternateBankContactExtensionNumCtrl}}</div></td>",
        "</tr>",
        "<tr><td style='border-bottom: thin solid #000000;' colspan='4' ><h1>{{DeliveryPickUpInformation}}</h1></td></tr>",
        "<tr>",
        "<td><div>{{LoadingDockLbl}} *</div></td>",
        "<td colspan='3'><div>{{LoadingDockCtrl}}</div></td>",
        "</tr>",
        "<tr>",
        "<td><div>{{DeliveryOrPickUpLbl}} *</div></td>",
        "<td colspan='3'><div>{{DeliveryOrPickUpCtrl}}</div></td>",
        "</tr>",
        "<tr>",
        "<td><div>{{CompanyNameLbl}} *</div></td>",
        "<td colspan='3'><div>{{CompanyNameCtrl}}</div></td>",
        "</tr>",
        "<tr>",
        "<td><div>{{DescriptionOfGoodsBeingTransportLbl}} *</div></td>",
        "<td colspan='3'><div>{{DescriptionOfGoodsBeingTransportCtrl}}</div></td>",
        "</tr>",
        "<tr>",
        "<td><div>{{DeliveryLocationCodeLbl}}</div></td>",
        "<td colspan='3'><div>{{DeliveryLocationCodeCtrl}}</div></td>",
        "</tr>",
        "<tr>",
        "<td><div>{{ExpectedArrival}} *</div></td>",
        "<td><div>{{ExpectedArrivalFROMLbl}} *</div></td>",
        "<td><div>{{ExpectedArrivalTOLbl}}</div></td>",
        "<td>&nbsp;</td>",
        "</tr>",
        "<tr>",
        "<td>&nbsp;</td>",
        "<td><div>{{ExpectedArrivalFROMCtrl}}</div></td>",
        "<td><div>{{ExpectedArrivalTOCtrl}}</div></td>",
        "<td>&nbsp;</td>",
        "</tr>",
        "<tr>",
        "<td><div>{{AdditionalCommentsLbl}}</div></td>",
        "<td colspan='3'>{{AdditionalCommentsCtrl}}</td>",
        "</tr>"
    );

    if(ctx.ControlMode == 1){
        console.log("ctx contorl mode is "+ ctx.ControlMode);
        formTable = formTable.concat('</table>');
    }else{
        formTable = formTable.concat(
        "<tr>",
        '<td colspan="4">',
        "<input type='button' value='Save' onclick=\"SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('{{FormId}}')\" style='margin-left:0' >",
        '<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="" > ',
        '</td>',
        '</tr>',
        '</table>');
    }

    //Replace the tokens with the default sharepoint controls
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{LoadingDockNotification}}', text.NewFormText.LoadingDockNotification[getLang()]);
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{indicatesrequiredfield}}', text.NewFormText.indicatesrequiredfield[getLang()]);
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{BankContactInformation}}', text.NewFormText.BankContactInformation[getLang()]);
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{BankContactNameLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'BankContactName'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{BankContactNameCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'BankContactName'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{BankContactNumberLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'BankContactNumber'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{BankContactNumberCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'BankContactNumber'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{BankContactDepartmentLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'BankContactDepartment'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{BankContactDepartmentCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'BankContactDepartment'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{AlternateBankContactNameLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'AlternateBankContactName'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{AlternateBankContactNameCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'AlternateBankContactName'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{AlternateBankContactExtensionNumLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'AlternateBankContactExtensionNum'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{AlternateBankContactExtensionNumCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'AlternateBankContactExtensionNum'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{DeliveryPickUpInformation}}', text.NewFormText.DeliveryPickUpInformation[getLang()]);
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{LoadingDockLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'LoadingDock'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{LoadingDockCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'LoadingDock'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{DeliveryOrPickUpLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'DeliveryOrPickUp'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{DeliveryOrPickUpCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'DeliveryOrPickUp'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{CompanyNameLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'CompanyName'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{CompanyNameCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'CompanyName'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{DescriptionOfGoodsBeingTransportLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'DescriptionOfGoodsBeingTransport'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{DescriptionOfGoodsBeingTransportCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'DescriptionOfGoodsBeingTransport'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{DeliveryLocationCodeLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'DeliveryLocationCode'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{DeliveryLocationCodeCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'DeliveryLocationCode'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{ExpectedArrival}}', text.NewFormText.ExpectedArrival[getLang()]);
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{ExpectedArrivalFROMLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'ExpectedArrivaleFROM'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{ExpectedArrivalTOLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'ExpectedArrivalTO'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{ExpectedArrivalFROMCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'ExpectedArrivaleFROM'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{ExpectedArrivalTOCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'ExpectedArrivalTO'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{AdditionalCommentsLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'AdditionalComments'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{AdditionalCommentsCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'AdditionalComments'));
    //Setting form ID for the correct Submition
    formTable = formTable.replace("{{FormId}}", ctx.FormUniqueId);
    //Returning the design created.
    console.log(formTable);
    return formTable;
}


function getSPFieldRender(ctx, fieldName) {
    var fieldContext = ctx;

    //Get the filed Schema
    var result = ctx.ListSchema.Field.filter(function (obj) {
        return obj.Name == fieldName;
    });

    //Set the field Schema  & default value
    fieldContext.CurrentFieldSchema = result[0];
    fieldContext.CurrentFieldValue = ctx.ListData.Items[0][fieldName];
    //Call  OOTB field render function
    return ctx.Templates.Fields[fieldName](fieldContext);
}


function getSPFieldLabel(ctx, fieldName) {
    var result = $.grep(ctx.ListSchema.Field, function (e) {
        return e.Name == fieldName;
    });
    return result[0].Title;
}
```

It seems to be generating the correct HTML ouptut but afterwards I noticed that the  is added but not properly populated.

Not sure if this is happening to anyone else.  I've spent a bit of time researching and can't seem to find anything online about the Taxonomy fields with CSR and why it's behaving this way.

I have another  form in a different list with 3 taxonomy fields and I'm still only getting one of them to display.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the link  https://gist.github.com/sduschinger/0065535dc193bf6aca5d works correctly. The only difference is I had to change on of the variables to a global.

Here is the full code:

```
//Fixing Mulitple Taxonomy Fields
var taxonomyFieldsToFix = []; //Had to change this one from within the loading function to a Global for it to work correctly. 

//Main Function that allows the override to happen using js link in SharePoint 2013 or greater.
(function () {
    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render
    var formTemplate = {};
    formTemplate.Templates = {};
    formTemplate.Templates.View = viewTemplate;
    //Part of fix for metatada fields
    formTemplate.Templates.OnPostRender = [];
    formTemplate.Templates.OnPostRender.push(fixTaxonomyFields);
    //What actually overwrites the default table
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(formTemplate);

})();

function viewTemplate(ctx) {
    //HTML design Variable, doesn't have to be an html table
    var formTable = "".concat("<table width='100%' cellpadding='5'>",
        "<tr><td colspan='4' ><div><h1>{{LoadingDockNotification}}</h1>",
        "<p>(<!--<span class='ms-formvalidation'>--> * <!--</span>--> {{indicatesrequiredfield}})</p></div></td></tr>",
        "<tr><td style='border-bottom: thin solid #000000;' colspan='4'><h1>{{BankContactInformation}}</h1></td></tr>",
        "<tr>",
        "<td><div>{{BankContactNameLbl}} *</div></td>",
        "<td colspan='3'><div>{{BankContactNameCtrl}}</div></td>",
        "</tr>",
        "<tr>",
        '<td><div>{{BankContactNumberLbl}} *</div></td>',
        "<td colspan='3'><div>{{BankContactNumberCtrl}}</div>",
        "<span class=\"ms-metadata\">{{BankContactNumberDesc}}</span></td>",
        '</tr>',
        "<tr>",
        "<td><div>{{BankContactDepartmentLbl}} *</div></td>",
        "<td colspan='3'><div>{{BankContactDepartmentCtrl}}</div></td>",
        '</tr>',
        '<tr>',
        "<td><div>{{AlternateBankContactNameLbl}}</div></td>",
        "<td colspan='3'><div>{{AlternateBankContactNameCtrl}}</div></td>",
        "</tr>",
        "<tr>",
        "<td><div>{{AlternateBankContactExtensionNumLbl}}</div></td>",
        "<td colspan='3'><div>{{AlternateBankContactExtensionNumCtrl}}</div>",
        "<span class=\"ms-metadata\">{{AlternateBankContactExtensionNumDesc}}</span></td>",
        "</tr>",
        "<tr><td style='border-bottom: thin solid #000000;' colspan='4' ><h1>{{DeliveryPickUpInformation}}</h1></td></tr>",
        "<tr>",
        "<td><div>{{LoadingDockLbl}} *</div></td>",
        "<td colspan='3'><div>{{LoadingDockCtrl}}</div></td>",
        "</tr>",
        "<tr>",
        "<td><div>{{DeliveryOrPickUpLbl}} *</div></td>",
        "<td colspan='3'><div>{{DeliveryOrPickUpCtrl}}</div></td>",
        "</tr>",
        "<tr>",
        "<td><div>{{CompanyNameLbl}} *</div></td>",
        "<td colspan='3'><div>{{CompanyNameCtrl}}</div></td>",
        "</tr>",
        "<tr>",
        "<td><div>{{DescriptionOfGoodsBeingTransportLbl}} *</div></td>",
        "<td colspan='3'><div>{{DescriptionOfGoodsBeingTransportCtrl}}</div>",
        "<span class=\"ms-metadata\">{{DescriptionOfGoodsBeingTransportDesc}}</span></td>",
        "</tr>",
        "<tr>",
        "<td><div>{{DeliveryLocationCodeLbl}}</div></td>",
        "<td colspan='3'><div>{{DeliveryLocationCodeCtrl}}</div>",
        "<span class=\"ms-metadata\">{{DeliveryLocationCodeDesc}}</span></td>",
        "</tr>",
        "<tr>",
        "<td><div>{{ExpectedArrival}} *</div></td>",
        "<td><div>{{ExpectedArrivalFROMLbl}} *</div></td>",
        "<td><div>{{ExpectedArrivalTOLbl}}</div></td>",
        "<td>&nbsp;</td>",
        "</tr>",
        "<tr>",
        "<td>&nbsp;</td>",
        "<td><div>{{ExpectedArrivalFROMCtrl}}</div></td>",
        "<td><div>{{ExpectedArrivalTOCtrl}}</div></td>",
        "<td>&nbsp;</td>",
        "</tr>",
        "<tr>",
        "<td><div>{{AdditionalCommentsLbl}}</div></td>",
        "<td colspan='3'><div>{{AdditionalCommentsCtrl}}</div>",
        "<span class=\"ms-metadata\">{{AdditionalCommentsDesc}}</span></td>",
        "</tr>"
    );

    if(ctx.ControlMode == 1){
        formTable = formTable.concat('</table>');
    }else{
        formTable = formTable.concat(
        "<tr>",
        '<td colspan="4">',
        "<input type='button' value='Save' onclick=\"SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('{{FormId}}')\" style='margin-left:0' >",
        '<input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="" > ',
        '</td>',
        '</tr>',
        '</table>');
    }

    //Replace the tokens with the default sharepoint controls
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{LoadingDockNotification}}', text.NewFormText.LoadingDockNotification[getLang()]);
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{indicatesrequiredfield}}', text.NewFormText.indicatesrequiredfield[getLang()]);
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{BankContactInformation}}', text.NewFormText.BankContactInformation[getLang()]);
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{BankContactNameLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'BankContactName'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{BankContactNameCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'BankContactName'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{BankContactNumberLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'BankContactNumber'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{BankContactNumberCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'BankContactNumber'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{BankContactNumberDesc}}', getSPFieldDescription(ctx, 'BankContactNumber'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{BankContactDepartmentLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'BankContactDepartment'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{BankContactDepartmentCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'BankContactDepartment'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{AlternateBankContactNameLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'AlternateBankContactName'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{AlternateBankContactNameCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'AlternateBankContactName'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{AlternateBankContactExtensionNumLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'AlternateBankContactExtensionNum'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{AlternateBankContactExtensionNumCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'AlternateBankContactExtensionNum'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{AlternateBankContactExtensionNumDesc}}', getSPFieldDescription(ctx, 'AlternateBankContactExtensionNum'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{DeliveryPickUpInformation}}', text.NewFormText.DeliveryPickUpInformation[getLang()]);
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{LoadingDockLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'LoadingDock'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{LoadingDockCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'LoadingDock'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{DeliveryOrPickUpLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'DeliveryOrPickUp'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{DeliveryOrPickUpCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'DeliveryOrPickUp'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{CompanyNameLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'CompanyName'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{CompanyNameCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'CompanyName'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{DescriptionOfGoodsBeingTransportLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'DescriptionOfGoodsBeingTransport'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{DescriptionOfGoodsBeingTransportCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'DescriptionOfGoodsBeingTransport'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{DescriptionOfGoodsBeingTransportDesc}}',getSPFieldDescription(ctx,'DescriptionOfGoodsBeingTransport'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{DeliveryLocationCodeLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'DeliveryLocationCode'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{DeliveryLocationCodeCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'DeliveryLocationCode'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{DeliveryLocationCodeDesc}}', getSPFieldDescription(ctx, 'DeliveryLocationCode'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{ExpectedArrival}}', text.NewFormText.ExpectedArrival[getLang()]);
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{ExpectedArrivalFROMLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'ExpectedArrivaleFROM'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{ExpectedArrivalTOLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'ExpectedArrivalTO'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{ExpectedArrivalFROMCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'ExpectedArrivaleFROM'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{ExpectedArrivalTOCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'ExpectedArrivalTO'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{AdditionalCommentsLbl}}', getSPFieldLabel(ctx, 'AdditionalComments'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{AdditionalCommentsCtrl}}', getSPFieldRender(ctx, 'AdditionalComments'));
    formTable = formTable.replace('{{AdditionalCommentsDesc}}', getSPFieldDescription(ctx, 'AdditionalComments'));
    //Setting form ID for the correct Submition
    formTable = formTable.replace("{{FormId}}", ctx.FormUniqueId);
    //Returning the design created.
    return formTable;
}

//This function code set the required properties and call the OOTB (default) function that use to render Sharepoint Fields
function getSPFieldRender(ctx, fieldName) {
    var fieldContext = ctx;

    //Get the filed Schema
    var result = ctx.ListSchema.Field.filter(function (obj) {
        return obj.Name == fieldName;
    });

    //Set the field Schema  & default value
    fieldContext.CurrentFieldSchema = result[0];
    fieldContext.CurrentFieldValue = ctx.ListData.Items[0][fieldName];

    //Fix for Metadata Field in the render function
    if (fieldContext.CurrentFieldSchema.FieldType == "TaxonomyFieldType" || fieldContext.CurrentFieldSchema.FieldType == "TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti") {
        taxonomyFieldsToFix.push(ctx.CurrentFieldSchema);
    }

    //Call  OOTB field render function
    return ctx.Templates.Fields[fieldName](fieldContext);
}


//This function will go and get the labels of the forms for easy multilingual abilities.
function getSPFieldLabel(ctx, fieldName) {
    var result = ctx.ListSchema.Field.filter(function (obj) {
        return obj.Name == fieldName;
    });
    return result[0].Title;
}

//This function will go and get the labels of the forms for easy multilingual abilities.
function getSPFieldDescription(ctx, fieldName) {
    var result = ctx.ListSchema.Field.filter(function (obj) {
        return obj.Name == fieldName;
    });
    return result[0].Description;
}

function fixTaxonomyFields(ctx) {
    $.each(taxonomyFieldsToFix, function (i, fieldSchema) {
        var controlContainerId = fieldSchema.Name + "_$container";
        var controlInputId = fieldSchema.Name + "_$input";
        var controlContainer = document.getElementById(controlContainerId);
        SP.UI.Taxonomy.Utility.$S(controlContainer, fieldSchema);
        controlContainer['InputFieldId'] = controlInputId;
        controlContainer.setAttribute("class", "ms-taxonomy ms-taxonomy-height ms-long")

        SP.SOD.executeFunc('ScriptForWebTaggingUI.js', 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.ScriptForWebTaggingUI.onLoad',
            function () {
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.ScriptForWebTaggingUI.onLoad(controlContainerId);
            });
    });
}
```

**As a side note** If your new field shows up and is disabled, it's because it lost it's link to the Managed Metadata. (True story ;) ).

I really hopes this helps someone else out there as it was hard enough to find that link to begin with.